# How to process a serial of async event by using rxjava?

Tags: asynchronous, rx-java

I am new to Rxjava and I've searched a lot on google. But not very useful for my problem.
My situation is a Living App using third party SDK. but the process of entering living room is quit complex and out of controlling.

The about overall process like this:

1. get liver's room info from app's server --- Async
2. enter living room by calling SDK's api ---Async
3. if succeed, join the chat group by calling SDK's IM api ---Async
4. then update the UI with the last step's result.

Each step relies on the previous step's result and callback is not in same IN/OUT type, so it is very hard for me to coding this with rxjava.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your async calls in an observable using Observable.fromEmitter, like this:

```
return Observable.fromEmitter(new Action1<Emitter<GetRoomModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Emitter<GetRoomModel> emitter) {
        AsyncFunction yourAsyncFunction = /* ... */
        final AsyncFunction.Listener listener = new AsyncFunction.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(RoomInfo roomInfo) {
                emitter.onNext(roomInfo);
            }
        };
        yourAsyncFunc.doAsync(/* data */, listener);
        emitter.setCancellation(new Cancellable() {
            @Override
            public void cancel() throws Exception {
                // cancel your async call
            }
        });
    }
}, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
```

You can do the same for each async call and then you can chain them up.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll have a try and give you a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect to give you a proper source code about what your app can do without any code base. 
I suggest you before start coding anything try to read/understand the observer pattern

Here you can see how the strucuture of the Observer pattern works

```
          Observable.just(getRoomInfo())
                  .map(info -> sdkApi(info))
                  .map(response -> joinChannel(response))
                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())//-->This make your pipeline async.
                  .subscribe(res -> updateUI(res))
```

And here you can see some documentation and practical examples about how RxJava works.
https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: Thanks for replying, but map operator is a sync process and when I set the generic type to int(room id), the following step's api not using a int parameter. So I wanna get some advice for selecting operator.

Comment: Ups I forgot to add the subscribeOn, now the pipeline is Async